# Is there MOFET with Id is between 10-14A at Vgs<4.2V?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, powermosfet

I am new to the area of working with MOSFETs. For my current project I need a suitable MOSFET or any other transistor, that should work as a switch. My output controlling voltage from controller IC is in the range of 4 to 4.3V. So I need a MOSFET / any transistor that should turn ON at this voltage level and should allow a minimum current of 8-15Amps with some considerable Rds(ON). Someone kindly suggest me a suitable transistor. I have gone through lot of available MOSFETS but none suits my application.

Comment: Product recommendations are considered off-topic here.

Comment: We have no idea of your application, so how can we suggest? There’s plenty of mosfets that will pass way in excess of your current requirements with 4V in the gate. Depends on the specs.

Comment: Look at component selector at http://www.digikey.com. there should be quite a few.

Comment: look for the irlz44n, a logic level n channel fet.

Comment: Look for Logic Level FETs. These have specified performance with 5 V or even 3.3 V on the gate.

Comment: Logic level or even sublogic level. The rdson tend to be bad however. Are you so cost constrained to not being able to use a gate driver?

Comment: To answer this question postmortem: Yes. there is.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this search I made for you at Digikey.

Those are all MOSFET transistors with a current of 8-15 A and a gate threshold maximum of 3.8 V.

Rdson and the package are your degrees of freedom.

Sorry about the length of the URI.

---

[Digikey Product search results](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?s=N4IgjCBcoKwOwAYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iAMxyIAsAnCALrEAOALlCAMocBOASwB2AcxABfYgDYE05CDSQseIqQrU4ADga6W7LpF4CR4qSFlaFSlQWJlIlAEwMaVGCGIu38r67g0niB0dDDSDFZ%2BNHRIxHTSME6yQd5wdBBRaU4p-nRUOdF0BWkemXRwxXSRIKkwsTX%2BMBkNNIlBoVoIYL4tcE5FXlpJYKU1Q9Ld7TBaYRWDw0wy7jM9TkMMSSnrVPVr3qNrVP0HWkfxW2fVh-2LY0dNF05tg%2B5gu6dNzYdN2S9NA3cmidXqtTlo6L87uCAYdwcDwVcwXULjMvkj8i8ZqMOl0TiEXFsQjtCXk0UTIWtyhDCWkMcEEsMaedBnUCSyEMT2VQ0XUjkEYEdwTyOXS1ryYTMOaDEn0tjKAdJlvA5U44CcZT0dowEKMtQw5EE9QhqnqwJDTQDTbqEIwwHNqDaGGATY6nM09U5za66R7La7Na77R6XYw2Q7GJzw64-RHrRGQ65btIYnUvgxFc72hNpDmcgkYAd0wXVkXpu04GAnYWEsk-NJOtXOiX68a851bi5629y5WwKL01owGn6FcGPQO2OdbtJw8-IhnsEGDAYhP5zCZ4WAps4lR4hycgFIy5D%2BvD5uqFQS4fV7vp3Ac6P7%2BED9JEC%2B0genfbj07Hxs7zoo6DmqOTAd%2BER2kBdq3FUqo2qBzrTuCBp%2BMhE5Ckh6TNIwjACkEfTlHSBEfsQxE9FUbwgXEDLpPh-RaNUBE6HRtosRsbF0vETa3ARDAArxoy8T0vH2n0dT1GJXR0ay0k6rJolPK2Mh1OUQQJDa1TqYwamJFU7SwSMOk3EZyLKU8kIMnhcSnM6FnLn2OnpACtolI5hnKek9oJOkmkFloXl%2Bb50xJgW%2Bo6YOzQJIOdmDgq0x2uFmbKYOIVDJFEyqTIGUwbunTVHkVRURYEymcVIzpSMdI5iMColaMObuFVirLmpzX1c19rlL2CoxIwSYJJGqaFa1ArpQKTUCrViAWa%2B%2B5ZfQrXzvhES0Mt-mMREnRrYO22QnAm38ZtgmbcJm0bQxPERGFpFXc0%2B06HtV2cS29Zremb2iVd516Dd%2BoSboCCPfqh36qd%2BqffqG36pdTp3boYDOdMXR3TKkJNAgOqMTKgnLm%2BpG4yjGX4WE7kgGq2bE2qnVfpli4aSjao8fAtZkzAS7CWzyr40uOVSij6b89Ie1s4q%2BETD9wT3tDYtOFJpGKgEYutEr95K9S8uWGLsg8dV9QuaVT5DlrZrtP5tBEa%2BYb3luQRaPWtHEHbyG2-bdJOyELvgva7u3E7C5%2B6Mfs9H71R%2B779Ys07Eye0LMduxHgcR%2BR6YJOHdvexH1QCpSkJR7c2fQp7FZF2jNpOUX2IvcH9arXESOqp724gIOl6cUMS3EOjOre32ya2yMbrtLodv1IOiS5wPdIF1QvvdHx-dwgvzLN86tODuCvuy3pjuy6VQw6rnu%2Bcb%2BCWd2kK227vAJDDPof9Bjl8xIfObPwkQ92svQyDqPaxGzvETYlcF-S%2BF9-4MSCBsBGdJIEe2IDA0YMDqiQNKsg5oyDIQFVkHrb%2B2gIFujCHgkY9pkFILdCzSB0c4FkOgWQgEFDK66Rod0HoFDiFkNIXPQheMQCQOLksIWLUqF2k4tMPo9ReEsLdLXYI614JCMCI7cEos4g019kowOI9r7%2BWfIo2go8zbNAYjofROhDGgzdqDa%2BoNA6g29qDUOoNfbg3qOjI4diECK0duDKxHibEeODqDUeGxcxeKSNTABDikgOJnjYmeASZIqKoOsCBOY35wNST0FShwUkPhyTonhOZPEFNfHQwpLDClIMKbcFOW10ldhyUMBp0CHwIIfMQnM11ilOhyexOprgsy6TRoKJJPTWnhEqYgPWoQMYYJwZCdMiBsICg2PM2azTEDkXrmMyhPCdjSNcB4pBezqlHEmHA05xDTlHJCCc0I2ET7XIXK4Nm4j3DdPOZzCBbyWFvKOWzE5TpqlP2IU-LOHJ4AIKfkCjk4iYjcggekNYCK%2Bywr7Gg9IfJiBvCeBeII2KBTYlEYPOuKxmj4pnniwGy56j4oduAKlsD6VPGXrS%2B0tLbj4tnEygskJOUAk5aMTlPROXVE5RyqlOyuJyDZRK3lEr%2BUSsFRK4VErqY5jLFiiVoqqV8IsJeHFlKniyk1Uatu3IQncqNqwEAnBuB8CEGISQcC2bWAwDgOw6hHDBA8UA9oCANjz2tbaow9rTBOvAE4S8rrlDurUA4ZwYQdSrC3LLLYyZGVrHTT6P2OQA00tlnxMlBadlmn9SzUI958rwDHKbLItarIgE%2BCzUaJtO6eiXPyYsowCz-M7ULAExYRln0PPyPi4I1JmlTTIbwSY3QRDxTXPIC7tF0m6NoslNc%2B5YvrA2Zd68939D3bi7dDEYhHo5Tuod4Ad0szXQxDdRi2X1n-HiyNVRV3mTPVi8yHbv0Cgft%2B%2BIBZX3hAId%2ByZ-K4L%2BtfYs3lcEkoRumh%2B6aoqkj3xA5Gjlmbb2Zpdd%2Bu2W6I0Ee7cMj9-lSYhFZPaaeRb-JTsbcMgdwypmsizsMwVawbbgY2Kh-aDcsU7FslmTo3CUVvrxTsSNq7JOlTE2B8ARxAYcsUxSgTW82WKd-Qpt0f9tNDhpac7SAn9WCovELZTsFeW5Sbn2WCor9Wk1lkkBRNRAY1xSIDSZPZgkedVPJpzapRVpD7Ly4LC4P4jEFWFjlaozTCvvCmPFCXW3gGS2S5LbKEuhCS%2BmoLyYG12ny6F-LmX8sxeTCWhLFrCvlBpQl6RNXVZYoSztZryZGltaqPylr8X2uldYp1%2Beg2ovJhrW1-4OXEh1ZopN%2BF43Ix2lpKF2kUWhSrYhOl8Ekaktbe7TabwptVTbeaxsTFwRpjwGPuqqLGxaJBsMMYB1ZgsVXWjbYONGgkD3btSYR1EhzDZC9QAWxILgdA%2BAuDMAkEAA)